# "Undefined function or variable" in GUIDE

Tags: matlab, function, user-interface, undefined

I have a script who replace some values. The problem is when i click the action button again, this give me error :

> "Undefined function or variable 'function'.  Error in
>   matlab.graphics.internal.figfile.FigFile/read>@(hObject,eventdata)redenumire('oldname_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))"

How can i solve this ? I'm totally at the start with Matlab, and i can't find a response for my question on internet. I have only one cd, so my directory doesn't change in time.
The code is :

```
function renamebtn_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
dir=get(handles.directorytext,'String');
if ~strcmp(dir,'')
PathName=handles.PathName;
calea=handles.PathName;
cd(calea)
client=handles.client;
new_name=get(handles.newname,'String');
old_name=get(handles.oldname,'String');
eval(['load ' ,client])
*action*
end
```

Running step by step,  loading everything I need in the workspace without jumping over the steps. In "oldname", I have nothing noted. On the internet / official site / forum, I have not found anything to help.

Comment: Can you put some break points to check where it goes wrong? Are you sure it goes wrong in this function or is it possible that it goes wrong in the code that calls the function `renamebtn_Callback`? Also, check the content of `hObject, eventdata and handles`.

Comment: Looks like the problem is in `oldname_Callback` function...

Comment: `eval` everywhere... hh!